# How to get array contents in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to echo a response (array) in PHP, but its not returning the desired value.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$array = file_get_contents('http://wen.com/api.php?id='.$id);
echo $array[0]; // it returns A, while I need Friday here
echo $array[1]; // it returns r, while I need Tuesday, 17 November here


?>
```

the response from file_get_contents, is:

```
Array ( [0] => Friday [1] => Tuesday, 17 November [2] => Tuesday, 17 November [3] => Friday )
```

EDITED:

The code of the api that I am using obove in file_get_contents, is :

```
$html =  file_get_contents("$url");



 $dom = new DomDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML($html);
            $dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
            $elements = $dom_xpath->query('//span[@class="nowrap"]');
            foreach($elements as $data){
               $array[] = $data->nodeValue;
            }

print_r($array);
```

Comment: It looks as though `file_get_contents` is returning a string with the value `Array ( [0] => Frid..`.  How is this file generated, it may be better in something like JSON.

Comment: Seems like some debug dumps were left in the API

Comment: replace `print_r($array);` by `echo json_encode($array);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:
I just replaced print_r($array); by echo json_encode($array);